# Why do two identical redstone contraptions not do the same thing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was experimenting with redstone manage to build the first example were everything works thine. I've built the exactly same thing in my building but there it won't work any ideas why?

(the delay is the same on both)

Comment: *"Temporary movie for gaming.stackexchange.com"* ? I believe it should be a permanente movie. Don't delete it, as it is part of the question, and it will make the question incomplete for future readers.

Comment: Okey I won't delete it

Comment: Link to video is dead

Comment: ... and because the video is dead and the asker hasn't been seen in 6 years, it's impossible to determine what question is being asked, meaning this should be closed as "unclear what you're
 asking"

Answer (score 7):

There are some glitches with redstone, the most likely cause is that it's the direction which the contraption is facing is causing the delays not to work.

The two sets of pistons are changing state at exactly the same time, but one set has to be handled first, due to the different orientations of the pistons, in the second one they are changing in the wrong order causing this glitch.

Comment: so theres nothing to do but hope for a fix?

Comment: @Jkguitar It can't be fixed, not really, your best bet is to rotate the mechanism and try and get it to fit.

Comment: I rotated the mechanism but it didn't work anyway

Comment: @Jkguitar Did you try all rotations, because that _should_ be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The orientation of redstone contraptions can affect how they work.